# не получается сделать дамп в mysql

Tags: java, mysql

проблема в следующем,
пишу в консоль mysql mysqldump -u имя_пользователя -p имя_базы_данных > путь_и_имя_файла_дампа, вылетает ошибка error (42000) You have an error in your SQL syntacsis.

Comment: `mysql -u user_name -p pass` - открыли mysql, и уже там `mysqldump db_name > database.sql`

Comment: `mysqldump` - это самостоятельная программа, а не команда консольного клиента `mysql`.